# Tensor Products of Modules (restriction and extension of scalars)

Tags: modules, tensor-products

Let $\phi:A \rightarrow B$ be a ring homomorphism, $M$ be an $A$-module, and $N$ a $B$-module.

Prove that

$$N \otimes_B (B \otimes_A M) \cong N \otimes_A M$$ as either $A$ or $B$-modules.

We know that $B \otimes_AM$ is a $B$-module and $N$ is an $A$-module via extension and restriction of scalars. We have that $N \cong N \otimes_BB$.

Is it legal to do this: 
$$N \otimes_B (B \otimes_AM) \cong (N \otimes_BB) \otimes_AM \cong N \otimes_AM$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep; and that's exactly the approach I'd use.

But if you're nervous, that argument also suggests how to write down an actual function that gives the isomorphism:

- The forward direction is $n \otimes b \otimes m \mapsto nb \otimes m $
- The backward direction is $n \otimes m \mapsto n \otimes 1 \otimes m $

and then you simply need to show that both functions are well-defined and are inverses.

---

To show these definitions are well-defined, we use the fact that I've expressed their values on pure tensors. Recall:

> Let $U$ be a right $R$-module and $V$ be a left $R$-module. There is a one-to-one correspondence between
>
> - Functions $f : U \times V \to W$ such that $f(u,v)$ is $R$-linear in both variables
> - Linear maps $g : U \otimes_R V \to W$
>
> And these are related by $f(u,v) = g(u \otimes v)$.
>
> Furthermore, if $U,W$ are left $S$-module, then if $f(u,v)$ is $S$-linear in $u$ if and only if $g$ is $S$-linear.

This extends inductively to repeated tensors; e.g.

> Let $U$ be a right $R$-module, $V$ be a left $R$ module and a right $S$-module, and $W$ be a left $S$-module. There is a one-to-one correspondence
>
> - Functions $f : U \times (V \times W) \to X$ such that $f(u,v,w)$ is $R$-linear in $u$ and $v$, and $S$-linear in $v$ and $w$
> - Linear maps $g : U \otimes_R (V \otimes_S W) \to X$
>
> And these are related by $f(u,v,w) = g(u \otimes v \otimes w)$.

You can derive this by applying the two-factor version to $U$ and $V \otimes W$, and then again to $V$ and $W$.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It's clear to me that those two functions are inverses. I'm not sure how to show that they are well-defined and bilinear.

Comment: @BartoloColon. Were you able to show the bilinearity?

Comment: @Jaynot No, I haven't.

Comment: I am naming the first map $\phi$. Observe that $\phi(r_1n_1 +r_2n_2, b \otimes m)  = ((r_1n_1 +r_2n_2)b \otimes m) = r_1n_1b +r_2n_2b \otimes m = r_1(n_1b \otimes m) + r_2(n_2b \otimes m) = r_1\phi(n_1, b\otimes m) + r_2 \phi(n_2, b\otimes m)$ @BartoloColon is it clear? You should be able to figure out that of the second component.

Comment: @Jaynot Thanks, it's totally clear.

Comment: Can you figure out the second component part? You need to do this before you can conclude that its bilinear. Give it a try and let me see what you got.

Comment: @Jaynot $\phi(n \otimes b \otimes r_1m_1+r_2m_2)=(nb \otimes r_rm_1+r_2m_2)=(nb \otimes m_1)r_1+(nb \otimes m_2)r_2=r_1 \phi(n\otimes b \otimes m_1)+r_2 \phi(n\otimes b \otimes m_2)$

Comment: Good. Use comma instead of the tensor product you used after writing n. The goal is to show that $N \times (B \otimes_A M) \rightarrow N \otimes_A M$ induces $N \otimes (B \otimes_A M) \rightarrow N \otimes_A M$

Comment: @BartoloColon I hope you know  the ring where the $r_1$ and $r_2$ lives in right for both cases?